# Test was successful , but got a Class Not Found Exception

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am getting this error given below :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, If I run the below code :

```
@Test
public void alert() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

    capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.android.apis");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos");

    capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "1000");

    driver = (AndroidDriver) new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Please let me know why this error is being thrown, have I missed any jar .

I am using :

Selenium 3.0.0 , Java Client 4.2.1 Jar , Selenium Android Driver Jar and Appium 1.16.4.1

Comment: `RemoteWebDriver` is part of `Selenium-Standalone-Server.jar`. so download the jar and use it instead of `Java-client jar`

Comment: Could you share the stack trace for `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 0):

Use jar 
selenium-api-2.53.0
selenium-java-2.53.0
selenium-remote-server-2.53.0
selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0
java-client-4.1.2

Comment: Hi Mahipal and Akhilesh , thanks for the help, but still it did not work, I tried using the below code but  still in vain :

Comment: driver = (AppiumDriver<WebElement>) new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
  TouchAction tAction=new TouchAction(driver);
  WebElement e=  driver.findElementByName("Views");
  
  tAction.moveTo(e).perform().press(e);

Comment: See All I need to do is, scroll down in an native android App and click a link , which is part of a list:  Appname is APIDEMOS , available in Play store